FIX for 'touch' command is not working in windows issue
enter image description here
enter image description here
If you are getting this error message when trying to use the 'touch' command and don't have node installed then simply install and use Gitbash by following the short tutorial below:
https://youtu.be/5zcgSzRfk_E
I tried using 'touch' on command prompt to create multiple files at the same time.
